# how to reduce complexity in regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have ***a regex*** which finds all kind of money denoted in dollars,like *$290,USD240,$234.45,234.5$,234.6usd*

```
(\$)[0-9]+\.?([0-9]*)|usd+[0-9]+\.?([0-9]*)|[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*usd|[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*(\$)
```

This seems to works, but how can i avoid the complexity in my regex?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106510/techniques-for-simplifying-a-regular-expression-by-hand

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23566410/simplifying-regular-expression

Comment: There is this -> http://ivanzuzak.info/noam/webapps/regex_simplifier/

Comment: It does not finds "$.0", for example.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to make the regex a bit shorter by collapsing the currency indicators:
You can say `USD` OR `$` *amount* instead of `USD` *amount* OR `$` *amount*. This results in the following regex:

```
((\$|usd)[0-9]+\.?([0-9]*))|([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*(\$|usd))
```

Im not sure if you'll find this less complex, but at least it's easier to read because it's shorter

The character set `[0-9]` can also be replaced by `\d` -- the character class which matches any digit -- making the regex even shorter.
Doing this, the regex will look as follows:

```
((\$|usd)\d+\.?\d*)|(\d+\.?\d*(\$|usd))
```

### Update:

- According to [@Toto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/372239/toto) this regex would be more performant using non-capturing groups (also removed the not-necessary capture group as pointed out by [@Simon MᶜKenzie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622391/simon-m%E1%B6%9Ckenzie)):

  ```
  (?:\$|usd)\d+\.?\d*|\d+\.?\d*(?:\$|usd)
  ```
- `$.0` like amounts are not matched by the regex as [@Gangnus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/715269/gangnus) pointed out. I updated the regex to fix this:

  ```
  ((\$|usd)((\d+\.?\d*)|(\.\d+)))|(((\d+\.?\d*)|(\.\d+))(\$|usd))
  ```

  Note that I changed `\d+\.?\d*` into `((\d+\.?\d*)|(\.\d+))`: It now either matches one or more digits, optionally followed by a dot, followed by zero or more digits; OR a dot followed by one or more digits.

  Without unnecessary capturing groups and using non-capturing groups:

  ```
  (?:\$|usd)(?:\d+\.?\d*|\.\d+)|(?:\d+\.?\d*|\.\d+)(?:\$|usd)
  ```

Comment: Removing the brackets around your main two alternatives will make it even simpler...

Comment: @Simon MᶜKenzie I personally prefer to keep those brackets since they make it easier to see where the alternatives of the alternation begin and end

Comment: Fair enough - different tastes!

Comment: Just for info: Easier to read but less efficient! Also non capture groups are better than capture ones if you don't care to catch them.

Comment: @Gangnus I do not agree that my answer is incorrect. Granted, it does not match `$.0`, but the question is how to *reduce the complexity* of a regex that works for them, and the question does not have `$.0` as one of it's test cases.

Comment: @ScintillatingSpider I know. I haven't downvoted your answer. But if a question looks how to improve a piece of code, having errors, we should first remove the error, shouldn't we? BTW, my answer also is not full - it matches -0 and 0001

Comment: @Gangnus Fair enough. Still, the OP might know `$.0` will not occur during the intended use. (Or they might not, so I did -- and still do -- totally agree with you raising this concern. I also did not think of this case.) I only feel that "Incorrect" is not the right word until we know if `$.0` has to be included but was overlooked by the OP :)

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](https://regex101.com/r/vqsVse/3)

`^(?:\$|usd)?(?:\d+\.?\d*)(?:\$|usd)?$`

Comment: That can be fixed by pulling the `\.` out of `[\d\.]` (resulting in `[\d]+\.?`). More importantly, **this regex also matches digits *without* currency indicators**. Fixing this will need lookarounds, making the regex more difficult

Comment: It also matches digits with two currencies: `$12.USD`

Answer (score 0):

Reducing the complexity you are reducing the correctness. The following regex works correctly, but even it doesn't take lowcase. (but that could be managed by a key). All other current answers here simply haven't the correct substring for the decimal number.

```
^\s*(?:(?:(?:-?(?:usd|\$)|(?:usd|\$)-)(?:(?:0|[1-9]\d*)?(?:\.\d+)?(?<=\d)))|(?:-?(?:(?:0|[1-9]\d*)?(?:\.\d+)?(?<=\d))(?:usd|\$)))\s*$
```

Look [here](https://regex101.com/r/rAJLc0/8) at the test results.

Make a correct line and only after that try to shorten it.